# While scraping the website through scrapy in python getting the following error:

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

> Error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character
>   u'\u201c' in position 0: character maps to

Code : # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
import scrapy


class Spider1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider_1'
    allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/' ,
        )

    def parse(self, response):
     x=response.xpath('//*[@class="quote"]')
     for quotes in x:
        text= x.xpath('.//*[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first()
        author= x.xpath('.//*[@class="author"]/text()').extract_first()
        Tags= x.xpath('.//*[@class="keywords"]/@content').extract_first()

        print '\ n'
        print text
        print author
        print Tags
        print '\ n'
```

Problm: if i use `extract_first` only then it's throwing the error else we use only extract. it work fines.

Could anyone please help as i am new to programming world and looking forward for positive solution.

Comment: 2.7 have a lot of issues with unicode, try using python 3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `.encode()` your Unicode strings before print:

```
print text.encode('utf-8')
print author.encode('utf-8')
print Tags.encode('utf-8')
```